# Keras fit: What if my steps_per_epoch is fewer than the number of batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I read online that `steps_per_epoch` is defined as dataset size/batch size. So basically, it is the number of batches to be seen/learned in each epoch.

In the below code, I have 8 batches after processing with the Time Series Generator. So if I use
`steps_per_epoch=1`, does it mean that only 1 batch has to be seen/learned in each epoch?

```
# univariate one step problem with mlp
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from pip.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

# define dataset
series = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) # 10 samples before processing by the Generator

# define generator
timestep = 2
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(series, series, length=timestep, batch_size=1) 
# After processing, 8 batches with 1 sample each

# define model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=timestep))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# fit model
model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=200, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, and your model will see always the same batch, this happens because the generator gets called again after every epoch, you run into problems only when the generator can`t provide more batches than the ones specified in `steps_per_epoch`.

In this case you will get an error that the generator has run out of data.

The main point to remember is that with a generator you are not going through all the database, and this is because the generator gets re-initialized every time you start an epoch.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the below. If instead steps_per_epoch = 8, the whole dataset will be being seen/learnt:
The main point to remember is that with a generator you are not going through all the database, and this is because the generator gets re-initialized every time you start an epoch.

Comment: if you set ``steps_per_epoch`` for example to ``2`` one could think that your models sees the 8 batches in 4 epochs, so you could think that the models sees the first 2 batches in the first epoch, the third and the fourth in the second epoch, the fifth and the sixth in the third epoch and the last ones in the fourth epoch, BUT THIS IS NOT THE CASE....  what will instead happen is that your model will see the first 2 batches EVERY epoch, the model will NEVER train on the other 6 batches

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the steps_per_epoch? Why would users want to train on fewer than their whole training set? Thanks

Comment: it's not for flexibility, if you have a generator you HAVE to specify the number of batches, cause the model has no way to understand how much batches the generator can generate before running out of data

Comment: to give you an idea: if you specify a number of ``steps_per_epoch`` higher than the number of batches that the generator can produce the model will give you an error, but this error will appear only when the model reaches the end of the generator during the first epoch, not during the initialization of the model, this is because the model does not check the generator before starting execution, he just trust the numbers you give him